# Make sure that all expects are called with Mocha / Chai

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

How do I make sure that every expect was called? For example the below test would pass even if the `AccountManager.addAccount('tim', '123456');` would throw an error as the second expect is never called then.

[Tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) handles this with `t.plan(2)`. Is there something in Mocha/Chai, too?

```
it.only('should test for taken username', done => {
    AccountManager.addAccount('kai', 'pazzword').then(result => {
      expect(result.ok).to.be.true;

      return AccountManager.addAccount('tim', '123456');
    }).then(result => {
      expect(result.ok).to.be.true;;

      return AccountManager.addAccount('kai', 'buzzword');
    }).catch(error => {
      done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not as convenient as with tape, but there is an official wiki article that should cover exactly what you need:

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Assertion-counting

You could still switch to tape completely or just for these tests where you need this feature though.